# can not be inputted because no notifications Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token)

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

This's form:

```
<form>
        <label for="Name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30"><br>

        <label for="Address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30"><br>

        <label for="Name">Telephone</label>
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" size="30"><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="create">
    </form>
```

This's code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function){
        $("#create").click(function(event)){
            event.preventDefault();
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var address = $("input#address").val();
            var telephone = $("input#telephone").val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/People/person",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {name: name, address: address, telephone: telephone},

            success: function(data){
                console.log(name, address, telephone);

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have an error in your syntax. Change `$("#create").click(function(event)){` to `$("#create").click(function(event){` and add the closing bracket to the end of your click event.

Comment: Please have a question in future posts, and include the error message in the question instead of the title.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `)` after `(event))`.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#create").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = $("input#name").val();
                var address = $("input#address").val();
                var telephone = $("input#telephone").val();
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/People/person",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {name: name, address: address, telephone: telephone},

                success: function(data){
                    console.log(name, address, telephone);

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function){` also incorrect

Comment: @FastSnail sorry I didn't notice that one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Double syntax error, firstly:
`$(document).ready(function) { // has to be (function() {`

Secondly:
`$("#create").click(function(event)) { // only needs 1 ) behind event`

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#create").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var address = $("input#address").val();
        var telephone = $("input#telephone").val();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/People/person",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                name: name, 
                address: address, 
                telephone: telephone
            },

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(name, address, telephone);
            }
        });
    });
});
```